# nginx won't respond on some ports

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

My problem is that I can not add another port to my existing nginx config.
I have disabled the firewall on the ubuntu server with this command:

```
sudo service ufw stop
```

in sites-available I have this file named file.conf:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com example.com;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/user/project;
}

location /files/ {
    root /home/user/download/;
}
}
server{
    listen 8080;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
        location / {
    include         uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/project.sock;
}
}
server{
    listen 8001;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

location / {
    include         uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/project.sock;
}
}
```

I had the 8080 part earlier and this worked in past and now, but 8001 is not working. I disabled the firewall so I think the problem lies elsewhere.

I also ran this command:

```
 sudo netstat -napl | grep 8001
```

which returned this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3475/nginx -g daemo
```

thanks for your help and support

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: @TarunLalwani it times out! or as chrome would say:
This site can’t be reached

boomrang-app.ir took too long to respond.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Do you see anything in nginx? If not then this is a DNS issue

Comment: there is no log (error and access) in nginx. it answers to port 8080 so it shouldn't be dns issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the issue!
the issue problem was that I used cloudflare for dns and cloudflare only let me use some ports listed here:

For requests made via HTTP:

80
8080
8880
2052
2082
2086
2095

For requests made via HTTPS:

443
2053
2083
2087
2096
8443

hope it helps some other people facing this problem!